# Creating SonarQube Dashboard for Javascript, but UT coverage is zero

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm running Jenkins Job to create SonarQube Dashboard

```
sonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:javascript-lcov-sq-scanner
sonar.projectName=Test Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=webapp

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin=jacoco

sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

Then I doubted that if this is because I did not configure sonar.tests

I also checked SonarQube Doc on
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
But I found sonar.tests is not compatible with maven

[Here is screenshot for Sonar dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDkZf.jpg)

In the link about we can see that all other items are ok, including Bugs & Vulnerability, Code Smell and Duplications, but only Coverage is not created.

Comment: Pls go through [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import) official documentation from SonarQube how to display Code Coverage in dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Suresh! I have read the doc in the link and then in SonarCube I went to Administration -> Configuration -> General Setting -> Javascript -> LCOV Files = 'webapp\test\unit\lcov.dat' but still failed and lcov.dat is an empty file and really exists. Do you have any new idea? thank you so much in advance!